# How to count achievements by genre from an array of game objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Sorry if something similar has been asked before, but I couldn't think of a way to phrase my question to find a result!

If I have an array of game objects...

```
const games = [{title: 'Halo 3', genre: 'FPS', achievements: 7}, {title: 'Fallout 3', genre: 'RPG', achievements: 6}, {title: 'Far Cry 3', genre: 'FPS', achievements: 12}]
```

How do I get the following result, which adds together achievements by genre?

```
{ FPS: 19, RPG: 6}
```

Here's what I have so far, which isn't quite right:

```
const achievementsByGenreTally = (games, dataKey = 'genre') => {
return games
  .reduce((acc, game) => {
    if (game[dataKey]) {
      acc[game[dataKey]] = game.achievements }
    return acc
    }, {})
```

};

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is almost right, but you need to sum all achievements values instead of just assigning them to objects' properties (Also, you need to handle case when the property is missing, because if you try to sum any number with `undefined` you will get `NaN`).

```
const achievementsByGenreTally = (games, dataKey = 'genre') => {
    return games
        .reduce((acc, game) => {
            if (game[dataKey]) {
                acc[game[dataKey]] = (acc[game[dataKey]] || 0) + game.achievements
            }
            return acc
        }, {})
};
```